# Solspace Freeform Pro + composer and Error Page

Tags: solspace-freeform, error-pages, composer

Based on Solspace Freeform [documnetation](http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/error_page)

> The Error Page function allows you to bypass the native EE error message template and create and customize your own. Simply create a new EE template and add in the applicable variables below, along with anything else you typically use in your templates (template tags, variables, or embeds). This function is available for all use in all form functions such as Freeform:Form, Freeform:Composer, etc. Make sure you specify the error_page="freeform/error_template" parameter in the form you'd like to use this error template.

but where I can define `error_page="freeform/error_template"` parameter when I'm on a composer editor? I have try to add it to the Composer Template as Template Params but still is using default EE errors message page.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Solspace support team:

> Ideally, put the code for the Freeform error page alone in its own
>   template (eg. /contact/error), i.e. not with other, regular EE code.

In my case that tip works. Not sure which part of EE code interfere, but will dig deeper in that issue to find out.